# How to validate radio buttons in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

This is my code i want that when i submit the form and radio button hasn't checked it should change the radio button outline red. How to change the outline 
color of radio buttons?

```js
$('#btn').click(function () {
    if ($('input[name=gender]:checked').length <= 0) {
        $("#bordergen").css('border-color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $("#bordergen").css('border-color', '#ccc');

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Gender<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="bordergen" type="radio" class="flat" required='required' value="Man" name="gender">
                    Man
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input id="bordergen" type="radio" class="flat" required='required' value="Women" name="gender">
                    Woman
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
            <input type='submit' id="btn" name='btn' value='Submit' class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    if ($('input[name=gender]:checked').length <= 0) {          
        $("#bordergen").css('outline', '1px solid red');
    }
    else {          
        $("#bordergen").css('outline', '1px solid #ccc');
    }
});
```

please try this....

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily change the color of a default radio.

But you can use a custom radio script like: http://icheck.fronteed.com/

or simply change the color of the text label.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function.

We can apply CSS in HTML label not radio button.

```js
$('#btn').click(function () {
    if ($('input[name=gender]:checked').length <= 0) {      
        $('input[name=gender]').css('outline', '1px solid red');
    }
    else {        
        $('input[name=gender]').css('outline', 'none');

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Gender<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" class="flat" required='required' value="Man" name="gender">
                    Man
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" class="flat" required='required' value="Women" name="gender">
                    Woman
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
            <input type='submit' id="btn" name='btn' value='Submit' class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Would you please check my above snippet?